# Multiline Label On UIButton Swift

Tags: xcode, button, swift, label, multiline

I've been trying to get a sync button to display `Last Sync at (time&date)`. But All I get is one line with shortened text.

```
// Sync Button

syncBtn.frame = CGRectMake(15, height-60, 120, 40)

syncBtn.addTarget(self, action: "syncBtnPressed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

syncBtn.setTitle("Last Sync: Never", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

syncBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

syncBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

syncBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1

syncBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 5

syncBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 10)

syncBtn.alpha = 0.5

syncBtn.titleLabel?.sizeToFit()

syncBtn.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

syncBtn.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2

self.view.addSubview(syncBtn)
```

This is the function to get and set the date on the label

```
func printTimestamp(){
    var timestamp = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: .ShortStyle, timeStyle: .ShortStyle)
    self.syncBtn.titleLabel?.text = ("Last Sync at: " + timestamp)
}
```

Anyone able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SetTitle method instead of .text , when you use .text it sets the title text but the constraints are not updated accordingly hence you need to use SetTitle method and set the adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth to true

```
self.syncBtn.setTitle(timeStamp, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
self.syncBtn.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Comment: look here for my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46723070/label-disappear-when-changing-font-size-to-25-in-swift

Answer (score 6):

create a UIButton with Multiple lines of text

> Possible  programtically

```
  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool){
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
      btnTwoLine.setTitle("Mulitple line", forState:     UIControlState.Normal)
      btnTwoLine.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping;

    }
```

Comment: plz look here for my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46723070/label-disappear-when-changing-font-size-to-25-in-swift