# label disappear when changing font size to 25 in Swift

Tags: swift, autolayout, label, uistoryboard

I have a table view and two labels inside it. The second label(description label) has Hundreds of line. when I set font size of description label to 21 it's working. Why description label goes to dissappear when I am changing font size to 25? How to resolve it?
I have also set auto resize cell height for increase size.

[image: following image will help you understand constraint and autolayout.]
description label attribute inspector
[image: attribute inspector pic]
alse code screenshot is
[image: this]

image for disappear label when size is 25
[image: disappear one]

label only show text when frame is under 8000 and for more text is not showing.

[**github link for problem**](https://github.com/dineshsharma1/ProblemDemo)

Comment: i did it with scroll view but result was same.

Comment: give lines to 0 in attributes inspector

Comment: Please take a look at custom cell at link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwlRP3pZ5N1VakZ6ckh3OXdiLWc/view?usp=sharing with title and description. Please row height to automatic dimension and can change your font in cell for row at indexpath

Comment: ya i did numbers of line 0 to make it infinite.

Comment: is that working ?

Comment: numbers of line is already set 0

Comment: not working i think it's a bug in xcode.

Comment: can you show a screenshot of your page

Comment: @MidhunKMohan added code above

Comment: You want both of the labels of dynamic size right..??

Comment: both labels are dynamic height and working with font size of 21 but not with 25.

Comment: Can you post you screen shot for the disappearing one.?

Comment: there is two `UITableViewDelegate` method `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat `   and
       `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat `  then
        `return UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in each `func` try it and let me know the result

Comment: yes please implement func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
    those static value is according to your need.. :) 
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }

Comment: implemented both function but result is same

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 200
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

Comment: table view scrolling but text not showing

Comment: @MidhunKMohan look for problem  at github

Comment: https://github.com/dineshsharma1/ProblemDemo

Comment: @dineshsharma is your problem solved ? , If not, then comment our esyimated height for table cell. make it all static. Try then . I am working on your project.

Comment: what kind of app you are working on  mate. Its insane to display such big label that too inside a table. Please refer any Standard app like FB, they dont use big text assigned to label inside tabel. They have detail view on next screen. I will suggest you to use UITextView.

Comment: thanx for your suggestion. but result was same with text view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156732/discussion-between-vijay-avhad-and-dinesh-sharma).

Answer (score 1):

You should check the following steps:

1. Give the number of lines to 0 if you don't need how many lines can
   be there. Specific number of lines can be given only when you know
   the exact number of lines.
2. Give the size of label to hold the content.
3. Check for constraints Exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Cell height should be dynamic.Have you given cell height dynamically.If you don't know how to give cell height dynamically use scrollview .

Answer (score 1):

@dineshsharma.. Lets try this one and let me know if you are still facing the problem.
This is for top label.

[image]

And for lower label set this.

[image]

And in attribute inspector set **lines** to 0 for both labels. And please implement height for row at index and estimated height tableview delegates.

Comment: @dineshsharma In my opinion there should not be such issue.There must be some thing with your constraints.I have tried same thing and is working fine for me...

Comment: give your label text more than 1000 lines.

Comment: frame working fine. table is scrolling but label text not showing after label frame 8000 of label frame in my case.

Comment: i am using less than 21 font size.  and i am working on it.

Comment: i don't why its not working for you.I recently tried for your problem no matter of font size it is working for me for both the labels.

Comment: it's only work when the size of label frame under 8000. Use long text.

Comment: minimum line should be 1000

Comment: you are setting the height for the label.?

Comment: github link  for problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156742/discussion-between-dinesh-sharma-and-niroj).

Comment: as soon as i solve this issue i will provide you.I am Xcode 7.3 user.I have to download and setup the xcode. :) :) :) or you can find me on facebook :)

Answer (score 0):

iOS 12 and below UITextView and UILabel is invisible when its height is 8192. I can solve this problem below codes. But this time there is a problem in orientation. label is not positioned correctly. This problem does not exist on iOS 13 and later.

```
lbl.sizetofit()
lbl.isScrollEnabled=true
lbl.isScrollEnabled=false
```